# python multiple inheritance, calling base class function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, inheritance

I was just trying something with multiple inheritance in python. I come up with this

```
class ParentOne:
    def foo(self):
        print("ParentOne foo is called")

class ParentTwo:
    def foo(self):
        print("ParentTwo foo is called")

class Child(ParentOne, ParentTwo):

    # how is this working
    def call_parent_two_foo(self):
        super(ParentOne, self).foo()

    # This does not work
    def call_parent_foo(self):
        super(ParentTwo, self).foo()

    def call_super_foo(self):
        super(Child, self).foo()

    def foo(self):
        print("Child foo is called")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    child = Child()
    child.foo()
    child.call_super_foo()
    child.call_parent_two_foo()

    # child.call_parent_foo() #This gives the below error
    # super(ParentTwo, self).foo()
    # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

and it gives the following output

```
Child foo is called
ParentOne foo is called
ParentTwo foo is called
```

I am getting confused as to how calling of `super(ParentOne, self).foo()` is evaluated in this case. As per my understanding `ParentOne` class does not have any idea of the methods and attributes of `ParentTwo` class. How does super works in case of multiple inheritance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python constructs a method resolution order (MRO) when it builds a class.  The MRO is *always* linear.  If python cannot create a linear MRO, then a `ValueError` will be raised.  In this case, your MRO probably looks like:

```
Child -> ParentOne -> ParentTwo -> object
```

Now when python see's a `super(cls, self)`, it basically looks at `self` and figures out the MRO.  It then uses `cls` to determine where we are currently at in the MRO and finally it returns an object which delegates to the *next* class in the MRO.  So, in this case, a `super(Child, self)` call would return an object that delegates to `ParentOne`.  A `super(ParentOne, self)` class would return an object that delegates to `ParentTwo`.  Finally a `super(ParentTwo, self)` call would delegate to `object`.  In other words, you can think of `super` as a fancier version of the following code:

```
def kinda_super(cls, self):
    mro = inspect.getmro(type(self))
    idx = mro.index(cls)
    return Delegate(mro[idx + 1])  # for a suitably defined `Delegate`
```

Note that since `super(ParentTwo, self)` returns a "Delegate" to `object`, we can see why you're getting an `AttributeError` when you try `super(ParentTwo, self).foo()` -- Specifically the reason is because `object` has no `foo` method.

Comment: Is their a way to see/get MRO

Comment: @AnuragSharma -- `inspect.getmro` should give it to you.  IIRC, you can also access it via the magic `__mro__` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
class X1:
    def run(self):
        print("x1")

class X2:
    def run(self):
        print("x2")

class X3:
    def run(self):
        print("x3")

class X2:
    def run(self):
        print("x2")

class Y(X1, X2, X3):
    def run(self):
        print("y")
```

Given an instance:

```
y = Y()
```

To call base class function:

```
super(Y,y).run()
super(X1,y).run()
super(X2,y).run()
y.run()
```

Output

```
x1
x2
x3
y
```

Similarity,

```
super(Y, y).run()
for cls in y.__class__.__bases__:
    if(cls != X3):
        super(cls,y).run()
y.run()
```

Output

```
x1
x2
x3
y
```

Answer (score 0):

You may understand `Child(ParentOne, ParentTwo)` as two separate inheritances within a chain: `Child(ParentOne(ParentTwo))`. Actually, `ParentOne` doesn't inherit `ParentTwo`, they are two separate classes, but the method `super` works like there's a chain of inheritances (in case of multiple inheritance only). I like this example to understand better what's going on (for Python 3.x):

```
class P:
    def m(self):
        print("P")


class A(P):
    def m(self):
        super().m() # -> B, if we inherit like C(A, B)
        print("A")


class B(P):
    def m(self):
        super().m() # -> P, if we inherit like C(A, B)
        print("B")


class C(A, B):
    def m(self):
        super().m() # -> A
        print("C")
        A.m(self)
        B.m(self)


c = C()
c.m()
```

It also considers a case if two parents inherit one base class. The script above prints:

```
P
B
A
C
P
B
A
P
B
```